# which multi-selection can be implemented in iphone (Registration page)

Tags: iphone, ios

I have multi-selection dialog(drop-down) in Android where user selects all options applicable to him in registration page.What can be used in Iphone for the same purpose ?
And selecting a few options will unhide few textfields which is mandatory to fill.
Let me know what can be my approach.Please share any open source code links.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing within the iOS SDK and that is for a good reason - those elements are just not pretty, funky and usable well enough when acting on a touch display.

Consider using [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW36) or [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW36) instead. Maybe also have a look at [Action Sheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW36).

Comment: Thanks for the reply miho.Is it good to have multi-select picker or multi-select tableview?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. If you have many properties: yes; otherwise I would recommend you to use simple toggle switches like you know it from the iOS settings app.

Comment: I have 14 items and few text fields to fill.Your approach is to have a button which would display modal view with toggle switches with 14 items and after selecting ,it will take me back to main registration page right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a very user friendly approach.

Comment: Thanks Miho it serves the purpose and keeps it simple rather than complicating it with Tableview.